# Open CV Vs NDK for Image processing

Tags: android

I am writing a program to manipulate images,ie change its color,brightness,contrast etc...
The DVM doesn't support the manipulation of images of size beyond a limit...Can any one tell me whether using Open CV will solve the issue(as this seems to be a better option than NDK)?
Or will I have to use NDK?
I have done  a lot of search and was not able to find answer..

Comment: Which NDK do you mean, Android NDK? If you're writing in C/C++ for Android you have to use NDK then. There are OpenCV ports for Android, too.

Comment: Yes android NDK,it is not mandatory for me to use the C/C++...it is just that I have to overcome the memory limitation issue,please help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are different options for Image processing in Android, see here for a comparison of the most popular options: see [Android Computer Vision JavaCV OpenCV FastCV comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673099/android-computer-vision-javacv-opencv-fastv-comparison) and [Image processing library for Android and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682878/image-processing-library-for-android-and-java)

Coming back to your question: If the images you deal are really very large so that they do not fit into the memory of the device, you need to process the images in small chunks called tiles.

If your images are not that big, I recommend you to use OpenCv, if you have to do anything more than very simple tasks such as brightness/contrast adjustment.

Comment: The problem is that If I manipulate them in chunks,I wont be able to rejoin them back as memory limits this....And Im sure that I cannot run the code in Java 'coz that will cause a memory limit error....And NDK is a good option..but I havent yet got any librbry which helps to process images of any format (PNG,JPEG,BMP) etc in NDK..please help

Comment: Can you try JavaCV and share the results?

Comment: Im trying to do it via NDK...will let you know the update once I am done