# Encoding image file

Tags: java, android, image

I have an int array of color r,g and b values. And I would like to encode them in a image file. Is there an easy method in android to write this data to an image? Also which image format should I use for this, png?

Comment: Using bitmap format (.bmp) will probably be easiest.  You will obviously need to set up all the required headers by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bitmap using your int array like this using [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)):

```
int[] array; // array of int RGB values e.g. 0x00ff0000 = red
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(array, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then write it out using [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)):

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
```

You can call [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to get a folder on external storage where you can save the file, if that's where you want to save it. You can get the path with get [File.getAbsolutePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html), e.g:

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/image.png";
```

You need the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission defined in your AndroidManifest.xml to be able to write to files on external storage.

Answer (score 0):

There are pure java implementations for reading and writting images: 
[Image processing library for Android and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682878/image-processing-library-for-android-and-java)

Probably some will work in android out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I believe ImageIO is available in Android. The ImageIO API provides methods to read the source image and to write the image in the new file format.

To read the image, simply provide the ImageIO.read() method a File object for the source image. This will return a BufferedImage.

```
//Create file for the source  
File input = new File("c:/temp/image.bmp");  

//Read the file to a BufferedImage  
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
```

Once you have the BufferedImage, you can write the image as a PNG. You will need to create a File object for the destination image. When calling the write() method, specify the type string as "png".

```
//Create a file for the output  
File output = new File("c:/temp/image.png");  

//Write the image to the destination as a PNG  
ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
```